# How to reduce exection time of FFT in a loop using OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

Unable to reduce the execution time of multiple FFTs using OpenMP.

Tried parallelizing the outermost loop, but thsi degraded the performance

```
typedef struct{float r; float i;}cmplx_f32_t;

double src[2*128];
double dst[2*128];
double w[128];
cmplx_f32_t data[128][4][256];

cffti(128, w);

for (k = 0; k < 128; k++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 2*32; i++)
        {
            src[i]   = data[i/2][j][k].r;
            src[i+1] = data[i/2][j][k].i;
        }

        cfft2(128, src, dst, w, 1);
    }
}
```

cffti and cfft2 and as given in the example at https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/fft_openmp/fft_openmp.html

If I disable the #pragma omp directives from the fft_openmp.c files, the run time is about 11ms. If we use #pragma omp, the total execution time is about 220 ms

Comment: Access to the given link is *forbidden*. But in the code that we can see,  the loop order generates a cache fault on `data` at every iteration. It may be the main limitation and parallelism will not improve memory access time  and adds extra overhead for thread creation and synchronization.

Comment: @Alain Link should be back up now. I tried matrix transpose before the loops for cache friendly implementation, but not much improvement. 2 threads is executing in 110 ms and 8 threads in 420 ms.

Comment: 11 ms is actually a very little time to get improvements without being penalized by the parallel overheads induced by the openmp directives. Try it with a bigger input size and report the results.